# webview showing webpages down the main layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

[image]

in this image i clicked the google button and it is showing the google website in a webview but it is also showing the main layout of the app above it(both buttons).i want to achieve when i will click on google button only the website should appear in webview not the buttons above it. here is my java and xml code . thanks in advance.

```
public class TestinglinkActivity extends Activity {
     final Activity activity = this;
     WebView webview;

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;


        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());



    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {

            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });


    Button btn_google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
    btn_google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.pk");
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();


          }
         }
     );


    Button btn_gmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail);
    btn_gmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             webview.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();


          }
         }
     );

           }   
};
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_click_login"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Google"/>

    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn_gmail"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="Gmail"/>

  <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </WebView>

</LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use setVisibility(View.GONE) for hideing button on click :

```
Button btn_gmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail);
Button btn_google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
    btn_google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

             webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.pk");
             btn_google.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             btn_gmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();


          }
         }
     );
```

Comment: i dont want to hide button onclick and only one button go invisible when i click one of them , and what if i have some text views below the buttons. i dont want to hide buttons after clicking . i want want to override the main layout by the webview .like new activity.

Comment: ps. how can i disappear the LinearLayout on button click

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

```
btn_google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
btn_google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.pk");
        webview.goBack();
        webview.goForward();
        TestinglinkActivity.this.btn_google.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TestinglinkActivity.this.btn_gmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

btn_gmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail);
btn_gmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
        webview.goBack();
        webview.goForward();
        TestinglinkActivity.this.btn_google.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TestinglinkActivity.this.btn_gmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

instead of

```
Button btn_google = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
btn_google.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
             webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.pk");
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();
      }
});


Button btn_gmail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gmail);
btn_gmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
             webview.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
             webview.goBack();
             webview.goForward();
      }
});
```

And Declare Button btn_google and btn_gmail globally.

Comment: i dont want to hide button onclick and only one button go invisible when i click one of them , and what if i have some text views below the buttons. i dont want to hide buttons after clicking . i  want to override the main layout by the webview .like new activity.

Comment: when i remove the scrollview from my main xml then webview shows on the whole screen . but i want to use scrollview too. hope this will help you to solve the issue.thanks